# comparing if void * contains 0 numbytes?

Tags: c, void-pointers

I need generic way to check if void * contains 0 till num_bytes. 
I came up with following approach. *p does not contain same type of data everytime hence cant do `*(type*)p`

```
bool is_pointer_0(void *p, int num) {                
    void *cmp;
    cmp = (void*)malloc(num);
    memset(cmp, 0, num);
    if (memcmp(p, cmp, num)) {
        free(cmp);
        return false;
    } else {
        free(cmp);
        return true;
    }        
}
```

The function allocates & frees up num bytes on every call, not pretty I think. 
Please suggest faster approaches. Appreciate the help.

**Update :**

How about this approach ?

```
   bool is_pointer_0(void *p, int num) {
        void *a = NULL;
        memcpy(&a, p, num);

        return a == NULL;
    }
```

Comment: I'd remove the C++ tag if I were you before you get buried in "Use a vector" comments.

Comment: No, tag the language you're actually using, or you'll get the wrong answers.

Comment: You need to define what is "better" for you: simpler? faster? prepackaged?

Comment: would like to go for faster approach, but looping seems unavoidable.

Comment: If you're worried about performance, you can probably vectorize the check for large `n`.

Comment: C style: The char* way is what I would do but for many (most?) Inputs you could do the short string optimization and keep a static array of a certain size with all zeros that you compare in a loop.  That allows you to allocate it only once and compare it only a small number of times. For example if the static array were 4k and the input was 10k you only need to call memcmp three times.  For C++ there are other ways...

Comment: the second one will die, you are copying dandom amount of random junk to your stack

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This code casts the void pointer to a char pointer. This allows the memory pointed at to be treated as a sequence of bytes. Then cycles through the specified length looking for non zero bytes. I do not know if the standards guarantee that this would work (ie casting a void* to a char* will provide a pointer to the raw bytes), but in real life it works

```
bool is_pointer_0(void *p, int num) {                
    char *c = (char *)p;
    for(int i = 0; i < num; i++)
         if(c[i]) return false;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: can we avoid looping  somehow ?

Comment: No; you can only hide the looping behind some library function. Frankly this answer is probably what I'd do, unless I _really_ needed to ask the underlying OS to somehow do it for me in one go.

Comment: just updated a different approach , can you guys take a look

Comment: And what does it do? How does it work? Please add explanation to make this answer more useful for future visitors. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can cast the pointer to a `char*` or `unsigned char*` and check the values of the elements.

```
unsigned char* cp = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(p);
for (int i = 0; i < num; ++i )
{
   if ( cp[i] != 0 )
   {
      return false;
   }
}
return true;
```

Answer (score 1):

Note: this approach may be better for long buffers well aligned.  Yet [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32699370/2410359) is fast due to simplicity.

Since the memory, if all zeros, must compare to itself, use `memcmp()`: a platform specific optimized function.

```
int memcmp0(const void *buf, size_t n) {
  #define TESTVALUE 0
  const char *cbuf = (const char *) buf;
  while (n > 0) {

    // If odd size, last byte not 0?
    if (n % 2 && (cbuf[n - 1] != TESTVALUE)) return 0;

    // 1st half matches 2nd half?
    size_t half = n / 2;
    if(memcmp(cbuf, &cbuf[half], half) != 0) return 0;

    n = half;
  }
  return 1;
}
```

This is easy to extend to other values other than `0` by changing `TESTVALUE`.

Note: at most `log2(n)` iterations.

Answer (score 0):

Another after accept answer:

Since the memory, if all zeros, must compare to itself, use `memcmp()`: a platform specific optimized function.

Check the first value and then use `memcmp()` to compare `ptr[0],ptr[1]`, then `ptr[1],ptr[2]`, then `ptr[2],ptr[3]`, etc.

```
int memcmpfast(const void *ptr, size_t n, char testvalue) {
  const char *cptr = (const char *) ptr;
  if (n == 0) return 1;
  if (cptr[0] != testvalue) return 0;
  return memcmp(cptr, cptr + 1, n - 1) == 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I'd probably go with something like this:

```
bool is_pointer_0(void* p, int num)
{
    return std::search_n((char*)p, (char*)p + num, num, 0) == p;
}
```

Or this:

```
bool is_pointer_0(void* p, int num)
{
    return std::all_of((char*)p, (char*)p + num, [](char c){return c == 0;});
}
```

Comment: And what does it do? How does it work? Please add explanation to make this answer more useful for future visitors. Thanks!